# Cannt figure out algorithm to edit JS object correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, algorithm

We are building and webapplication for our client, that is sort of an Netflix for books. But because of the license agreement with publishers, we need to do something like this (model situation):

1. user opens some book and reads 30 pages of it => we store that they read 30 pages
2. next month users opens that book again and reads another 25 pages (so he is at 55), but we only need to store the 25 for that month

Data the server gets from frontend is only:

```
{
 pages: number //( first month it would be 30, second it would be 55)
}
```

The algorithm I need is to only get from the 55 the 25 that they read that month.

The database stored object look like this:

```
"_id": "60cd3619af335d537c2cf6a5",
    "user_id": "CCYSYXf",
    "scripts": [
      {
        "max_pages": 31,
        "full_pages": 150,
        "percentile": 0,
        "_id": "60cd371c39d2df537007e8dc",
        "script_id": "-VQD0",
        "data": [
          {
            "_id": "60cd371c39d2df537007e8dd",
            "year": 2021,
            "months": [
              {
                "_id": "60cd371c39d2df537007e8de",
                "num": 0,
                "pages": 0,
                "vpc": 0
              },
              {
                "_id": "60cd371c39d2df537007e8df",
                "num": 1,
                "pages": 0,
                "vpc": 0
              },
              {
                "_id": "60cd371c39d2df537007e8e0",
                "num": 2,
                "pages": 0,
                "vpc": 0
              },
              {
                "_id": "60cd371c39d2df537007e8e1",
                "num": 3,
                "pages": 0,
                "vpc": 0
              },
              {
                "_id": "60cd371c39d2df537007e8e2",
                "num": 4,
                "pages": 0,
                "vpc": 0
              },
              {
                "_id": "60cd371c39d2df537007e8e3",
                "num": 5,
                "pages": 30,
                "vpc": 3.8000000000000003
              },
              {
                "_id": "60cd371c39d2df537007e8e4",
                "num": 6,
                "pages": 0,
                "vpc": 0
              },
              {
                "_id": "60cd371c39d2df537007e8e5",
                "num": 7,
                "pages": 0,
                "vpc": 0
              },
              {
                "_id": "60cd371c39d2df537007e8e6",
                "num": 8,
                "pages": 0,
                "vpc": 0
              },
              {
                "_id": "60cd371c39d2df537007e8e7",
                "num": 9,
                "pages": 0,
                "vpc": 0
              },
              {
                "_id": "60cd371c39d2df537007e8e8",
                "num": 10,
                "pages": 0,
                "vpc": 0
              },
              {
                "_id": "60cd371c39d2df537007e8e9",
                "num": 11,
                "pages": 0,
                "vpc": 0
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
```

What I tried is incrementing the number of pages read by month, but that doesn't work because for example, if user is on page 30, and then returns to page 29, it would count that as well. That can be avoided by condition, that (script.max_pages < req.body.pages) - max pages is the highiest page number for that book, but the problem with that is that user can also skip pages, for example: They are on 10, then skip to 15, and then return to 14. That condition would now prevent it from counting that page 14.

Comment: Sometimes simplifying the data structure will simplify the logic involved.  Since most books are of reasonable length, I think that an array in the database representing each page might be easier to deal with, both in populating and counting the pages.  The array can simply contain either a value representing an "unread" flag for the page, or a reference to the year/month that the page was read.